# Is it safe use for different threads one function?

Tags: pthreads

Is it safe use for different threads one function? Or I must use semaphores here?

```
static void *func1(void *arg)
{
    ...
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    ...
    pthread_create(&thread, &thread_attr, func1, (void *)data);
    pthread_create(&thread2, &thread_attr2, func1, (void *)data2);
    ...

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple threads use the same function.  You only need to use synchronization (semaphores, mutex, etc) if that function uses data that would be shared between the threads.  If all data is in data and data2, then no semaphores would be needed.